# My hover doesn't show when click on mobile device

Tags: html, css

So, im trying to make a responsive website only with html and css. So far so good. BUT, my hover effect will not show on click in my mobile. When I inspect the page on desktop, it shows on click, but not when the site is live on the web.

The strange thing is that i can copy the text that I want to show on click, but as I said, it will not show. So my thougt is that the text is there somewhere, but again, it doesnt show. PLEASE can someone help me? Im pretty new to this.

Down here is both my html and my css.

```
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
 }

  .tjanst-rubrik {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }

 .hoverbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 .hoverbox .hoverbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
 }
 .hoverbox:hover .hoverbox-layer_top:hover {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 .hoverbox .tjanst-text {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 .tjanst-bild {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 18em;
  height: 30em;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
 }
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hoverbox tjanst-bild" style="background-image: url(bilder/grava.jpg);">
        <p class="tjanst-rubrik">RÅDGIVNING</p>
        <div class="hoverbox-layer_top">
            <div class="tjanst-text">
                Har ni funderingar kring material, växtval, växtsjukdomar eller andra odlingstekniska åtgärder? Vi träffas hemma hos er och använder tiden enligt era önskemål.
                Pris: <b>2500 kr</b> inkl. moms
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
Kindly close this question as you have another question open for the same reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474603/the-hover-text-doesnt-show-when-click-on-mobile

Answer (score 2):

On mobile, the `:hover` event is triggered before the click event, which can cause issues with `:hover` functionality on touchscreen devices. Such events on touchscreen devices act more like a double-tap than an actual click.

You may be better off using an `onClick()` event with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! But I can not use Javascript unfortunately

Comment: @SebastianLinderoth May I ask why not?

Answer (score 0):

`.hoverbox .hoverbox-layer_top:hover` or `.hoverbox:hover .hoverbox-layer_top` should be sufficient for the `hover` rule (i.e. not two hovers.)

Comment: I've tried that but it doesnt work :(
Heres is the site live if tha's any help: http://breaback.se/tjanster.html

Answer (score 0):

isn hover for things with a cursor to go over it to activate the hover. I think you need to use the :focus for mobile devices example

input:focus bracket
  background-color: yellow;
bracket

for name and number text installs [like this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand how i can apply that så it only works on mobile devices.

Comment: @SebastianLinderoth You could use a `@media` rule in your CSS to specify `:hover` events for large screens (desktops) and use the `:focus` event for everything else (small screens, usually mobile devices).