# The hover-text doesnt show when click on mobile

Tags: html, css

Im pretty new to this and only work with html and css - and have a big problem.

I have a hover on my webpage, and if i inspect in the browser the hover is supposed to show on click on a mobile device. The hover works fine on desktop

But when the webpage now is live, the hover doesnt show on click in my iphone. I can see that the text is there somewhere, because I can mark it and copy. But as I said, it doesnt show. Can someone please help me?
The webpage with hover: http://breaback.se/tjanster.html

Code below

```
 .container {   
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
 }

  .tjanst-rubrik {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }

 .hoverbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 .hoverbox .hoverbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
 }
 .hoverbox .hoverbox-layer_top:hover {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 .hoverbox .tjanst-text {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 .tjanst-bild {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 18em;
  height: 30em;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
 }
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hoverbox tjanst-bild" style="background-image: url(bilder/grava.jpg);">
        <p class="tjanst-rubrik">RÅDGIVNING</p>
        <div class="hoverbox-layer_top">
            <div class="tjanst-text">
                Har ni funderingar kring material, växtval, växtsjukdomar eller andra odlingstekniska åtgärder? Vi träffas hemma hos er och använder tiden enligt era önskemål. Ca 2h hemma hos dig. Ni för anteckningar.<br>
                <br>
                Pris: <b>2500 kr</b> inkl. moms
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its working for me both in mobile view and in desktop view.
Can you try checking in some other mobile and see if this is specific to single device?

Comment: Hi! I just checked and youre right, it works fine in another phone and just checked on chrome on iphone and it works. Its Safari that is the problem. Do you know how i can solve it easy with just css html? I'm not allowed to use js. @Rajeev

Comment: Is it working in MAC Safari? There you can inspect element and check

Answer (score 0):

there is no mouse in the mobile phone to recognize the hover.
You need to use JavaScript and "onclick" Event to assign this feature to this div

Comment: Okej. Im not allowed in my course to use js. But the strange thing is that the click function works fine in other browsers than Safari.

Comment: visit https://usabilitypost.com/2010/05/12/css-hover-controls-on-iphone/ .it may helps you